# subdirectory install breaking existing links

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, installation, directory

I've had this issue several times now. While building a site, including some content, I keep WordPress in a subdirectory (say, `/wordpress/`). When putting it live, I move/copy 3 files out of the dir into the root, in accordance with the WordPress specifications here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

It works, but all the links already entered in content refer to `/wordpress/bla/bla` and will, after the move, return 'file not found'. Also, links previously sent in emails and links already indexed by Google will return file not found.

My question: Is this behaviour as designed, or am I doing something wrong?

Please note: My question is not how to fix it. It's easy enough to add some lines to the root `.htaccess` to say, "for every request inside `/wordpress/`, if it doesn't exist, remove the word `/wordpress/` and try again," so I'm surprised WordPress doesn't do that by itself.  This makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: There is really cool plugin you can use - Velvet Blues. It will change old links to new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. WordPress does not monitor the links within content, so it's up to you to change them when your structure changes.

Comment: well .. ok. so the issue sounds familiar ? i'm wondering why wordpress doesnt just add a rewriterule for in-directory links; it shouldnt have to change the content.

Comment: It's familiar. I usually go into PHPMyAdmin and run a couple of queries directly to update the links. Obviously one should back-up the DB before doing this or do a test run first.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, we used a "Search and Replace" plug-in for WordPress to mass change the content of a site that was moved to a new hosting server.

Not sure if this plug-in will work for you, but you can give it a try:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/